# How to check (within a smart contract) if an account has an associated smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, accounts

Is it possible to check if an account has a smart contract, from within a smart contract?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this project by NSJames might be able to help you.

https://github.com/nsjames/Account-Has-Code

I believe the idea is an existing contract you can ask if another account has code on it or not. 
See the example to see how you might be able to implement it.

Comment: This idea is very. Unfortunately, the project seems doesn't update and the check code data is not up to date